# Laravel - $query->where all the ids in an are matched

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am working on an API endpoint that returns a list of users that have all of the given services ID's.

In my case:

- Users can have many services
- Tables: 'users', 'services', 'service_user'

I am passing an array via Vue JS to my end point for example:

```
/endpoint/32,35,38
```

My query is currently:

```
$servicesArray = explode(',', $services);

$users = User::whereHas('services', function ($query) use ($servicesArray) {
            foreach ($servicesArray as $key => $value) {
                $query->where('id', $value);
            }
        })
        ->get();
```

The issue is that it seems to return now results, even if a user does have the correct services. My relationship is fine, and if I only pass one service to the endpoint it correctly returns a user that has that service assigned. I used whereIn before, but I need to only show users that have ALL of the services specified in the endpoint array.

Any obvious reason why what I have is not working as expected?

Comment: @BenRoob There is, but that returns all results where any of the array values are matching. I need these to only return where all array fields are matching.

Comment: Sorry, totally missed it... I'll delete my shit!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
$q = User::query();

foreach ($servicesArray as $key => $value) {
    $q->whereHas('services', function ($query) use ($value) {
         $query->where('id', $value);
    });
}

$users = $q->get();
```

Comment: Interesting idea, getting "Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string" currently so sorting that out before deciding if this way works.

Comment: In the original query, it seems like you are trying to find one service with all the three IDs. The idea of the answer is that you have to search for three services with one ID. I don't know if the idea is clear, but that's what I've tried to do.

Comment: Solved it using your idea but tweaked. The issue was that I need to name my query something like '$query' and then return $users = $query->get()

Comment: You are right, I'll edit the answer. It is nice that it works

Answer (score 0):

You can also use laravel hasmany realationship function for getting multiple records from other table.

**Example:**

---In your Controller use query like.

```
 $users = User::with('services')->where('id', $value)->get();
```

---And in your model's class use function services like this.

```
 function services(){
   return $this->hasMany('App\Service','user_id','id');
 }
```